# Passing data forward with delegate protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm trying to pass data forward from `viewA` to `viewB` using a delegate. The reason I am trying to use a delegate is `viewB` is a slide out menu - I am using the `SWRevealViewController` library for this function. However as a side effect - `prepareForSegue` is not called from `viewA` as it does not own `viewB`.

So it seemed like delegates are the way forward.

The problem is my delegate method is not called.

In `viewB` - I added a method that gets called when a pan gesture happens - which opens the side menu.

So this is what I did:

In `viewA` I declared the protocol:

```
@protocol firstViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
(void)sendData:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

Declared it like so in `viewA`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <firstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then in the pan gesture in `viewA`

```
-void)panGestureStarted:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

    NSString *dataToPass = @"Test sending data to second view";
    [self.delegate sendData:dataToPass];

}
```

Then in `viewB`:

```
#import "viewAController.h"
```

Conformed to the protocol

```
@interface BBFilterViewController : UIViewController < firstViewControllerDelegate>
```

Then in `viewB.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];


ViewAViewController *viewA = [[ViewAViewController alloc] init];
viewA.delegate = self;}



-(void)sendData:(NSString *)string{
NSLog(@"Data from viewA %@",string);}
```

The problem is in `viewB`.m the method: `-(void)sendData:(NSString *)string` is never called. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
ViewAViewController *viewA = [[ViewAViewController alloc] init];
viewA.delegate = self;
```

creates a new instance of `ViewAViewController`, sets its `delegate` and then destroys it. Instead of creating a new instance that never gets used (its view is never displayed) you should be finding the existing instance and connecting to that.

In this case, this would be using the sliding view controller to get the front view controller.

In this case however delegation likely isn't the best approach as the relationship sounds backwards. You're really just looking for `viewA` to pass some data to `viewB` and it can do that directly when provided with information about the sliding controller (which it already has). `viewA` is also not always in the same place necessarily, whereas `viewB` is.

So, just get `viewB` and send a message directly to it:

```
ViewBViewController *viewB = (ViewBViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)self.revealviewControler.rightViewController topViewController]; 
[viewB ...];
```

*(casts are required because the methods return superclass pointers and you need to call subclass specific methods, that applied to both the nav controller and the view B controller)*

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I find the existing instance? As viewAviewController is not the front view controller - my UITabBarController is as I wanted the whole tabbar to move of screen when the menu came out.

Comment: So where is `viewA`? Most likely you should change so that `viewA` sets itself as the delegate of `viewB` or just remove the delegate all together (just have `viewA` call `viewB` directly because `viewB` is always in the same place in the view controller hierarchy.

Comment: viewA is the second tab of my UITabBarController. viewA never calls viewB. It has self.revealViewController pan gesture added to it so that it reveals viewB. I'm not sure viewB is next to viewA. How can I check that? (Still new to iOS programming, sorry for the newbie questions)

Comment: It isn't next to as such, but `viewB` is `self.revealViewController.rearViewController` (or `rightViewController`)...

Comment: Oh I see. So I could pass the data forward by using self.revealViewController.rightViewController and assigning it to an instance of viewBViewControler class to get to a public property ? They way the instance of viewBViewController will have the same memory address as self.revealViewController.rightViewController? I'll test it out when I get back to my Mac. Thanks.

Comment: when I try assign the viewB like: ViewBViewController *viewB = self.revealviewControler.rightViewController = I get a warning in Xcode saying incompatible assignment. Even though rightViewController and viewBViewController are both UIViewControllers

Comment: `ViewBViewController *viewB = (ViewBViewController *)self.revealviewControler.rightViewController `

Comment: I found the problem. self.revealViewController.rightViewController is actually a UiNavigationController. Which makes sense as my side menu is embedded in a UINavigationController. How do I tell the compiler that this is actually a UINavigationController? I wanted to access navigationController.viewControllers - obviously the compiler doesn't like that since it thinks its a UIViewController - so the property viewControllers doesn't exist for UIViewController. Appreciate your assistance with this.

Comment: `ViewBViewController *viewB = (ViewBViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)self.revealviewControler.rightViewController topViewController];`

Comment: Awesome - that did the trick! Thanks! - can you update your answer and if you don't mind elaborating a little why I had to cast it like that - as before I did try casting with UINavigationController - but your way worked. I'll mark it as the correct answer too. Thanks again!!